# How to use toupper on char * in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, char, c-strings, toupper

So I have a problem with using toupper on char *. Let me show you what I tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char* shi = command->args[0]; //which is "binance"

    while(*shi) {
        toupper((unsigned char) *shi);
        shi++;
    
    }

    printf("Capitalized version is: %s",shi); // which should be "BINANCE".

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: What is `command`?

Comment: Not work? Does not even compile.

Comment: Sorry ! I am working on that project for 6 days straight, codes went into each other. Take a look again!

Comment: What will `shi` point to when you call `printf`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky command line argument, which in this case is "binance".

Comment: `toupper((unsigned char) *shi);` is wrong anyway, it should be `*shi = toupper((unsigned char) *shi))`;

Comment: `for (int i = 0; shi[i]; ++i) { shi[i] = toupper(shi[i]); }`?

Comment: @round_protector please [edit] and provide a [mcve]. Your code does not compile.

Comment: "does not work"is not sufficient to help you. Please describe in detail what happens.

Comment: @RetiredNinja seg fault.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it prints "Capitalized version is: ". So it does not see the string.

Comment: @round_protector it is quite normal that your last version prints `"Capitalized version is: "`. Hint: where does `shi` point after the while loop?

Comment: I guess out of the range of the string? @Jabberwocky

Comment: At the zero at the end of the string, just like you wrote your loop condition

Comment: @round_protector yes, more or less. Now you should understand why nothing is printed.

Comment: @round_protector Either you did something wrong or `command->args[0]` is not terminated properly or isn't writeable. That's the problem with code we can't see. Works fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/vj637djqr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
toupper((unsigned char) *shi);
```

has no effect. The result of the call of `toupper` is not used.

Also after this while loop

```
while(*shi) {
    toupper((unsigned char) *shi);
    shi++;

}
```

the pointer `shi` points to the terminating character '\0' of the string.. So the following call of `printf`

```
printf("Capitalized version is: %s",shi);
```

will deal with an empty string.

You should write for example

```
for ( char *p = shi; *p; ++p ) {
    *p = toupper((unsigned char) *p);
}
```